# AuthorizeAttribute constructor argument Roles equals string.empty meaning?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

this a question from some MCTS 70-515 Exam Practice tests.

please help with the correct  2 answers

---

You are implementing an ASP.NET MVC 2 Web application that allows users to view and edit data. You need to ensure that **only logged-in users** can access the Edit action of the controller. What are two possible attributes that you can add to the Edit action to achieve this goal?

(Each correct answer presents a complete solution. Choose two.)

1. [Authorize(Users = "")]
2. [Authorize(Roles = "")]
3. [Authorize(Users = "*")]
4. [Authorize(Roles = "*")]

Comment: i think 3 & 4 are correct but the practice test says 1 & 2 are correct

Comment: right, check the sourcecode in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A look at the source code of the `AuthorizeAttribute` shows that there is no wildcard "*".

It makes no sense if `[Authorize(Users = "")]` would result in "no one" can access the action.

### So Answer **1** and **2** is correct.

**Source code of the AuthorizeAttribute**

```
protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
    if (httpContext == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
    }

    IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
    if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
        return false;
    }

    if (_usersSplit.Length > 0 && !_usersSplit.Contains(user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (_rolesSplit.Length > 0 && !_rolesSplit.Any(user.IsInRole)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And the `Role` and `Users` propertie.

```
public string Roles {
    get {
        return _roles ?? String.Empty;
    }
    set {
        _roles = value;
        _rolesSplit = SplitString(value); // simple split by comma
    }
}

public string Users {
    get {
        return _users ?? String.Empty;
    }
    set {
        _users = value;
        _usersSplit = SplitString(value); // simple split by comma
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: I have changed this so it's now correct and just supplements dknaack's correct answer**

Decorating an action with `[Authorize]` means that the user must be authenticated.

So if you want any logged-in user to be able to access an action it's normal just to put `[Authorize]`.

dknaack has referred to the source code, so his answer must be correct, even though it seems slightly strange to me. But clearly right!

Just to add, if `_usersSplit` is like a normal split on comma then we'd expect `_usersSplit.Length` to be `1` when `_users =""` and I'd still be right, but I guess the split function is using the `RemoveEmptyEntries` option. Can't refer to the source for that as am afk right now (had knee operation yesterday, not allowed on computer just yet - lol).

Empty string is not a valid name for a user or a role. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74(v=VS.100).aspx

> You should throw an ArgumentException if any of the specified user
>   names or role names is an empty string and an ArgumentNullException if
>   any of the specified user names or role names is null (Nothing in
>   Visual Basic).

Comment: +1 Here is another good explanation: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/user-based-authorization-cs

Comment: Thanks. And thanks for the link. Anything by Scott Mitchell is usually pretty good! :-)

Comment: I thought I was sure, but apparently not. Thanks for the clarification. It's not how I'd have written that attribute though!